# ORA-00959: Tablespace '$name' does not exist when using impdp

Tags: oracle, migration, tablespaces, impdp

I'm new at Oracle databases. I'm executing an `impdp` command and encountered this error:

> ORA-00959: tablespace '$name' does not exist.

Is the only thing I can do is to create the `$name` tablespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the tablespace

or

remap the tablespace to use an existing one, with the `remap_tablespace` parameter:

```
impdp ... remape_tablespace=$name:$name2
```

Where `$name2` is the name of an existing tablespace.